# Error: Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => void', but got one of type '(dynamic) => Null'

Tags: json, flutter, api, parsing

My first project and newbie to flutter, unable to solve this after 2 weeks of trying.

I am trying to get request via API using GetX package and i got the error mentioned above.

Trying to parse JsonMap into a List and it's giving me the error mentioned.

I have tested and the StatusCode is 200, I am assuming its just not parsing correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Peace
JY

**Error message: -**

```
Error: Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => void', but got one of type '(dynamic) => Null'
```

**Controller:-**

```
class BlogController extends GetxController {
  final BlogRepo blogRepo;

  BlogController({required this.blogRepo});

  List<dynamic> _blogList = [];
  List<dynamic> get blogList => _blogList;

  Future<void> getBlogList() async {
    Response response = await blogRepo.getBlogList();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Got Data");        //this gets printed  
      _blogList = [];
      _blogList.addAll(Blog.fromJson(response.body).data);
      print(_blogList);       // not printing _blogList
      update();
     
    } else {}
  }
}
```

**Model:-**

```
class Blog {
  late List<Data> _data;
  List<Data> get data => _data;

  Blog({required data}) {
    this._data = data;
  }
  Blog.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      _data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach(
        (v) {
          _data.add(Data.fromJson(v));
        },
      );
    }
  }
}



class Data {
  int? id;
  Attributes? attributes;

  Data({this.id, this.attributes});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    attributes = json['attributes'] != null
        ? Attributes.fromJson(json['attributes'])
        : null;
  }
}


class Attributes {
  String? title;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? text;
  String? link;
  Image? image;

  Attributes(
      {this.title,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.publishedAt,
      this.text,
      this.link,
      this.image});

  Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    text = json['text'];
    link = json['link'];
    image = json['image'] != null ? Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null;
  }
}


class Image {
  Data? data;

  Image({this.data});

  Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }
}


class NestedAttributes {
  String? name;
  String? alternativeText;
  String? caption;
  int? width;
  int? height;
  Formats? formats;
  String? hash;
  String? ext;
  String? mime;
  double? size;
  String? url;
  Null? previewUrl;
  String? provider;
  Null? providerMetadata;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  NestedAttributes(
      {this.name,
      this.alternativeText,
      this.caption,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      this.formats,
      this.hash,
      this.ext,
      this.mime,
      this.size,
      this.url,
      this.previewUrl,
      this.provider,
      this.providerMetadata,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  NestedAttributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    alternativeText = json['alternativeText'];
    caption = json['caption'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
    formats =
        json['formats'] != null ? Formats.fromJson(json['formats']) : null;
    hash = json['hash'];
    ext = json['ext'];
    mime = json['mime'];
    size = json['size'];
    url = json['url'];
    previewUrl = json['previewUrl'];
    provider = json['provider'];
    providerMetadata = json['provider_metadata'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
  }
}


class Formats {
  Thumbnail? thumbnail;
  Thumbnail? large;
  Thumbnail? medium;
  Thumbnail? small;

  Formats({this.thumbnail, this.large, this.medium, this.small});

  Formats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    thumbnail = json['thumbnail'] != null
        ? Thumbnail.fromJson(json['thumbnail'])
        : null;
    large = json['large'] != null ? Thumbnail.fromJson(json['large']) : null;
    medium = json['medium'] != null ? Thumbnail.fromJson(json['medium']) : null;
    small = json['small'] != null ? Thumbnail.fromJson(json['small']) : null;
  }
}


class Thumbnail {
  String? name;
  String? hash;
  String? ext;
  String? mime;
  int? width;
  int? height;
  double? size;
  Null? path;
  String? url;

  Thumbnail(
      {this.name,
      this.hash,
      this.ext,
      this.mime,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      this.size,
      this.path,
      this.url});

  Thumbnail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    hash = json['hash'];
    ext = json['ext'];
    mime = json['mime'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
    size = json['size'];
    path = json['path'];
    url = json['url'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid the code and the information in the question and it is hard to guess where (at what line) do you get the error. Please extract the part relevant, and try to reduce the code and data in question to the bare minimum needed to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response.data` instead of `response.body` when you got the response.

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for the response, I tried, but it gives me an immediate error before even running it

Comment: Try to print the response from your api like:- print(response.toString()), print(response.body.toString()), print(response.data.toString()), and also print(response.runtimeType), print(response.body.runtimeType), print(response.data.runtimeType) whichever is allowed

Comment: I assigned **response.body** to a variable  and  print(response.body.runtimeType); and i get **JsonMap**  in return  .  I am trying to convert JsonMap into a List<dynamic> , I believe thats what the error is about , i stand to be corrected.